# Шифрование диска на Centos 6.8

Tags: linux

Добрый день. Есть сервер PROXMOX на Centos 6.8 на котором 2 физических диска.  На втором диске уже есть данные и его нужно зашифровать (кроме LUKS), подсказали что можно с помощью LVM сделать, но никогда этого не делал. Подскажите пожалуйста!
Спасибо

Comment: Ну так сделайте свою домашнюю работу, будут возникать вопросы по ходу -- задавайте!

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. В линукс есть насколько я знаю 4 варианта использования шифрования разделов\данных:

- LUKS - нативная система с ее помощью вы можете зашивровать как раздел так и создать контейнер в который можете поместить свои данные, диск при этом нуждается в очистке этот вариант вам не подходит скорее всего
- Truecrypt - позволяет создавать контейнеры, работает поверх уже существующей файловой системы. Алгоритм такой - выделяем место и указываем что это наш контейнер, исходя из того что на диске есть данные предположу что этот вариант тоже вам не подходит (есть еще аналог [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) базируется на TrueCrypt)
- eCryptfs - работает поверх фс. Алгоритм такой - берем директорию, создаем ключ (парольная фраза) и шифруем с помощью него все что попадает в директорию
- EncFS - аналог eCryptfs который может использовать пароль пользователя для шифрования директории

p.s. начиная с версии ядра linux 4.1 [добавлена поддержка шифрования файловой системы ext4 на уровне отдельных файлов и директорий](https://habrahabr.ru/post/327682/)

Вроде ничего не забыл, звиняйте ежели что-то пропустил.